# Why can I not successively increment a variable within a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add 10 over and over for every invocation of `d`. It stays 20 every time, why?

```
function d() {
    var c = [10];
    c[0] += 10;
    alert(c[0]); // always 20
}
d(); d(); d(); // supposed to be 20, 30, 40...
```

Comment: Read about [variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2c_Variables%2c_and_Literals#Variable_Scope).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You create a new array and assign it to `c` each time the function is called. That resets it.

Move the assignment so it is outside the function (so it only runs once).

```
var c = [10];
function d() {
    c[0] += 10;
    alert(c[0]);
}
d(); d(); d(); // will be 20, 30, 40...
```

But globals are good source of bugs, so it is considered good style to wrap such things in closures to minimise the use of globals.

```
var d =(function () {
    var c = [10];
    function d() {
        c[0] += 10;
        alert(c[0]);
    };
    return d;
})();
d(); d(); d();
```

Comment: Quentin - You can type very fast!

Answer (score 1):

[@Quentin already explained the reason for your problem and provided a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222022/why-can-i-not-successively-increment-a-variable-within-a-function/7222027#7222027). For more information about variable scope, have a look at the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Variable_Scope).

As an alternative, you can assign the value to a property of the function:

```
function d() {
    var c = d.c || (d.c = [0]); // initialize property if not set
    c[0] += 10;
    alert(c[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have is local variable. Which gets initialized to 10 every time you invoke the function.

Try using global variable as

```
var c = [10];
function d() {  c[0] += 10; alert(c[0]); // always 20 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
var c = 10;
function d(){
    c+=10;
    alert(c);
}
d();d();d();
```